# Unsafe Cryptographic Encryption error in Android

Tags: android-security

Remediation for Unsafe Cryptographic Encryption how to fix this issue.?

Any way to fix this issue.

Security alert

Your app contains unsafe cryptographic encryption patterns. Please see this Google Help Centre article for details.

Vulnerable classes:

> com.cardinalcommerce.shared.cs.utils.a.a

Comment: Did you solved that?

Comment: Not yet. I have found nothing specific to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Braintree SDK, this warning is coming from an internal dependency they have on the cardinal commerce mobile SDK. The issue in their Github repo was created today: https://github.com/braintree/braintree_android/issues/305.

So until they fix it and release a new version the warning will still show up in the Google Play developer console.